# Ember Data - Polymorphic relation to any type

Tags: ember.js, polymorphism, ember-data

Let say that I want to develop a feature to handle entity historic. When fetching historic entries, each historic entry could be bound to an application model entity.

To avoid creating a generic historic model and extend all the models in the application, how could I achieve the polymorphism?

```
//models/historicentry
export default DS.Model.extend({
    entity:DS.belongsTo('????', {polymorphic:true})
    ...
});

//models/post
export default DS.Model.extend({
...
}}

//models/comment
export default DS.Model.extend({
...
}}
```

In this example, how to allow a post or a comment to be the associated type of the entity relationship in the historicentry model whitout refactoring the post and comment models?

Using JSONAPI, the request to fetch the historic is

```
//GET /historic
{
    "data":[
        {
            "type":"historics",
            "id":1,
            "attributes":{ ... }
            "relationships":{
                 "entity":{"data":{"id":1, "type":"posts"}}
            }
        },
        {
            "type":"historics",
            "id":1,
            "attributes":{ ... }
            "relationships":{
                 "entity":{"data":{"id":1, "type":"comments"}}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I don't recommend trying to use polymorphism in Ember Data. By the time you're done, what remaining hair you have will be silvery white.

Comment: Damn! I'm already bold :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a common base model! I don't think its possible without.

Well you could try to use `DS.Model` directly. Maybe you can export `DS.Model` with `export default DS.Model;` without any `extend` in a file `base.js` and then use `belongsTo('base', ...)`
But I haven't tried this yet. Looks like an ugly hack if it works.